# How do brains find the peak/valley point on a curve?

Tags: neuroscience, brain

It costs O(n) time if we find the max/min value in a number sequence with the length n. However, if we convert this sequence into a curve and find the peak/valley point with our eyes, it will use much less time.
How do brains complete this computation? I guess the visual nerve process it in divide-and-merge, like breaking down the curve into small segments and comparing them in parallel. If this is correct, what is the size of the smallest segments?

Comment: You might read about orientation selectivity in V1. Receptive field size is a function of distance from the fovea.

Comment: The question is not very precise: e.g., if we know that there is only one minimum, and the sequence is sorted as it is for plotting a curve, then finding its minimum is trivial and rather quick. If there are multiple minima, then indeed we need to go element by element and we will find a minimum in $O(n)$... but we can do it in $O(n)$ for sequence of any length, whereas the eyes can do it only for finite resolution and finite picture size.